# Creating new objects in game loop vs reusing temporary object

Tags: java

There is Point class which contains two floats and can assign them. There is also a boat object of Boat class which has setPosition method that can assign only Point class.

```
    Point temp = new Point(0.0f, 0.0f);

    while (true) {
        temp.setX(boat.getX() + 1.0f);
        temp.setY(boat.getY());
        boat.setPosition(temp);
    }
```

vs

```
while (true) {
        boat.setPosition(new Point(boat.getX() + 1.0f, boat.getY()));
    }
```

Will the first approach be executed faster than the second? For me the second one runs twice as fast as first with 2 billion iterations, isn't it supposed to be optimized by JVM?

Comment: In the second you are doing 2 operations (`set**`) less but creating an instance every iteration. How about the memory footprint comparison?

Comment: You could measure yourself by using jmh (https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)

Answer (score 0):

You will not detect a significant performance difference if in the real application. Creating small objects like Point is not likely to become a performance bottleneck, because most of the work will happen inside boat.setPosition(). "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" (c). JVM optimization is an art and you will never be able to tell which code is faster by just looking at it (apart from the obvious situations, of course).

Taking this into account, you should concentrate on the design and readability of your code instead. Generally spealing, you should not reuse small value objects ike Point.

In the first approach you will use the same object in many places in your code and any changes done to it will be visible in all ojects which have a reference to it, which makes your code hard to understand, maintain and opens a potential for bugs.

An approach with an immutable object (your second code snippet) is a much better design. You should favor using immutable objects in this kind of situations. JVM is very good at managing small short-lived objects. You may want to look into https://immutables.github.io/ or Kotlin data classes if you decide to use immutable objects in your code.